# rasterImage() in R creates image with white border

Tags: r, graphics

This works properly, creating an image that fills the window:

```
z <- matrix(runif(500*500), ncol=500)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(z, col=grey(0:255/255),zlim=c(0,1))
```

But rasterImage() puts a border around the image, even though I set the margins to zero:

```
z <- matrix(runif(500*500), ncol=500)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
rasterImage(z,0,0,1,1,interpolate=FALSE)
```

I have tried all sorts of fixes using plot() and mar() parameters. Please tell me how to get rid of the border when using rasterImage().

I am using Windows 7, if that matters. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: This is not a solution for the above problem, but a workaround. An argument useRaster has been added to image() lately, and it will do the same thing as rasterImage, ie create the image with a bitmap rather than polygons:   image(z,col=grey(0:255/255),zlim=c(0,1),useRaster=TRUE)

Comment: +1 for a nice, reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to slightly overfill the plot area. It feels like a bit of a hack, but it works. I am not sure why it happens, but observe the difference between...

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
rasterImage(z,-0.03,-0.03,1.03,1.03,interpolate=FALSE)
```

... gives a very narrow white border. And...

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
rasterImage(z,-0.04,-0.04,1.04,1.04,interpolate=FALSE)
```

...plots over the border right to the edge. There is some kind of expansion factor being introduced somewhere, but this plots over it. Look closely at the border on the picture.
[image: rasters]

Comment: Thanks Simon! Your answer pointed me in the right direction. The solution is to do: par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),xaxs = 'i',yaxs='i'). The xaxs and yaxs arguments force R to use the actual limits I want (ie 0,1) without padding them out a bit.

Comment: @BillSimpson Perfect. I will bookmark this question because I will inevitably find that very useful to know in the future! Cheers Bill.

Comment: Sweet answer guys, hella useful.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Good idea there. Given that this is 2 years old, is there a better method? If so, could you please update your answer or write another answer altogether.